# Is it possible for a SF to SF gRPC pub sub connection?

Tags: platform-event, event-monitoring, publish-subscribe, grpc

All the examples I have come across show client applications in various languages create a connection. Is it possible for a SF to SF gRPC pub sub connection? That is not one using empAPi/CometD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. SF can only used cometD to consume for now.